# iOS set the autolyout in the animation view comply with all the device

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout

I have a question is about the autoLayout in iOS.

I was research long weeks, but I still not reach to my need action. /  \

I was build a animation view(container view). There have a click button in the container view.

Init status like these below photo:
[image]

The the click button, the container view will use animate (slide) to the bottom button upper.

And the container will cover the white part(bottom button upper part).

final wish like below:

[image]

And click the button at the container view. It will collapse the view back to the the init state.

I can write the code to control the constraint about the contaienr view.

```
 - (IBAction)slideBtnAction:(id)sender {
     if (isContainerOpen) {
    // 100 is for user click region
    // it is slide view action (close)
    [self replaceTopConstraintOnView:self.containerView withConstant: -self.containerView.frame.size.height + 40];
} else {
    // it is slide view action(open)
         [self replaceTopConstraintOnView:self.containerView withConstant:           self.containerView.frame.size.height - _btmBtn1.frame.size.height - 40];
}

[self animateConstraints];
isContainerOpen = !isContainerOpen;

 }

 - (void)replaceTopConstraintOnView:(UIView *)view withConstant:(float)constant
 {
     [self.view.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ((constraint.firstItem == view) && (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTop)) {
        constraint.constant = constant;
    }
}];
 }

 - (void)animateConstraints
 {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
 }
```

But the station is the container view fix the height and the animation can't slide to the correct position at the bottom upper position(cover white part).

I want to the container view can comply with all the iOS device. So the container view will dynamic height.

But I don't know how to set the container view heigh in the slide station.(the fix heigh I was implement in these code.)

Have anyone can help me how to achievement the effect?

Because I have set some autolayout in the storyboard.

So I up my simple project to the github[[here]](https://github.com/dickfala/slideTest.git).

Please give me some hint and tutor , thank you very much..

---------------------edit-----------

for @YuviGr

If I change the constraint (use your suggestion)

```
 // it is slide view action(open)
 [self replaceTopConstraintOnView:self.containerView
   withConstant: self.containerView.bounds.size.height - _btmBtn1.bounds.size.height];

 - (void)replaceTopConstraintOnView:(UIView *)view withConstant:(float)constant
 {
     [self.view.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ((constraint.firstItem == view) && (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTop)) {
        constraint.constant = constant;
    }
}];
```

}

When I click the button , the view was not animate to correct position.
like these
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a reference to the constraint you want to animate, in this situation i believe is the bottom constraint of the containerView.

Just control-drag from the Storyboard to the controller to create an IBOutlat (check out this tutorial if you don't know what to do [Link](https://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/ios-animating-autolayout-constraints/))

to get to the state where your containerView is visible (the second image) you can calculate your view's height and subtract the buttons height

```
constraint = self.view.bounds.size.height - button.bounds.size.height;
```

for the invisible (first image) you'll have to use a constant to deicide how high you want it

Comment: I don't know how to set the container view height in the autolayout, I was set the fix height now, but it's wrong effect. I need set the always heigh is achieve to the bottom button upper. If I set the fix height, it was can't achieve to comply with  all  the device. If you can, you can see my project the storyboard. thank you very much. really.

Comment: where are you creating the autolayout constaints? in StoryBoard?

Comment: In Storyboard, I had set initial value. then I use the code to set the constraints .Because it was slide animate.